# Why is the mod operator not defined for real values?

Tags: vhdl

I wanted to calculate and simulate clock phase shifting, when I ran into the problem that VHDL has no `mod` operator defined for REAL values.

I check my old VHDL book and this [online source](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/operator.html). Both mention `mod` for integers, but not for numbers (including floats).

GHDL also reports `mod` as unknown.

Example calculation:

```
constant Period     : TIME := 10.0 ns;
constant PhaseDelay : TIME := Period * (((Phase + 360.0) mod 360.0) / 360.0);
```

**Why is the mod operator not defined for real values?**

Modulo/Remainer definition for positive **integer** values a, b:
`a = (a/b)*b + (a REM b)`

This equation can be used for remainer calculation on negative numers, too. The modulo operation on negative numbers need some tricks to handle the sign, but it's also base on add, sub, mult, div.

Comment: It's even worse than you think. This is not a VHDL problem (nor any language). Modulus on real numbers is not even defined on a pure mathematical point of view. The reason is that there is no quotient / remainder notion with real numbers. They make sense only with integers.

Comment: Essentially, because division is exact.

Comment: Oooh .... `IEEE.math_real` comes with a `mod` operator defined as: `X = Y*N + mod (X, Y)`. As far as I can see it was introduced in VHDL-93.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modulo is well defined for integers, but not for reals. Modulo gives you the remainder of integer division `a / b`, but real division doesn't have remainders, it gives you a real...

For instance, if you perform 13 divided by 3. Integer division will give you a result of 4 with a remainder (modulo) of 1. Real division will give you approximately 4.333333333333, no remainder since it is exact (ignoring finite representation of number).

To get the modulo after real division of `a / b = c`, you would have to do something like `(c - floor(c))*b`. In the case of  `13/4` example, it gives you back 1.

Comment: Oh my ... I should have started my day with a big cup of coffee ... I see it now. I stopped my thoughts at the decimal point. If I would like to implement integer division and remainer on real numbers, what could be a good function name? `intdiv(a, b : REAL)` and `intrem(a, b : REAL)`

Comment: You can use `fmod`, I've seen it both in C++ and in graphic card shader language. What it performs is different than what I posted: `fmod(a, b) = a - floor(a/b)*b`, which is wrapping `a` around `b`. You may have to be careful about negative numbers though.

Comment: My goal is to normalize (clock) phase shifts into the range of 0.0 to 360.0 degree. Currently, it's done by an if-then-else function, which adds 360.0 if the value is negative. This allows only input values of range -360.0 to 360.0 degree. I'm not sure if anybody will use my function with for example 722 degree...

Comment: The range should be -180 to 180, or 0 to 360. At least, that is what I would expect `fmod` from C++ to do. -360 to 360 is redundant, although it is not a big issue. I don't know if `a - floor(a/b)*b` is the most efficient way to do it, but one thing is sure is that is will be slow... I would suggest you check your input and wrap it only if necessary, the comparaisons will speed up your code if your function is called most of the time with the right range of argument.

Comment: Oooh .... `IEEE.math_real` comes with a `mod` operator defined as: `X = Y*N + mod (X, Y)`. As far as I can see it was introduced in VHDL-93.